# passing variable to default controller in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

i have one default controller in codeigniter

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
```

as you know we can call this function

```
sitename/index.php
```

or

```
sitename/
```

**as i have url rewrite in .htaccess**

now i want to call same index function with parameter passing like

```
sitename/seo-services
```

where seo-services will be paramater passing to index function to load seo-services page.

as default syntax of codeigniter is

example.com/class/function/ID

i want in this formet

example.com/class/ID

where i want to skip the function for default (index) function of class

how can i do this?

Thanks

as you can see i am trying this for seo purpose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameters appended to your url are automatically converted to arguments to your method.

For example if you have a method called index index in your welcome controller, then http://www.example.com/index.php/welcome/index/[parametervalue] will automatically pass [parametervalue] to your method, assuming that you define your function to receive the parameter

```
class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index($parameterValue=null)
    {
      //do whatever you need here
      //note the default value just in case it is null
    }
}
```

If you want to make things shorter, you will have to define an alias in the config/routes.php file. Also, if you want to get rid of the index.php, you will have to configure your web server accordingly (either through .htaccess if using apache or web.config if using iis)

Comment: dear i did same but i got error 404 Page Not Found, actually i am trying to pass value to default controller and my url is like localhost/seo-services

Comment: As mentioned in the paragraph below the code. You first need to setup .htaccess (as mentioned in the doc here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html) . Then, you need to modify the routes in your application/config/routes.php (as explained in the doc here http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/routing.html )

Comment: i think i am unable to explain you, look default syntax is example.com/class/function/ID   i want example.com/class/ID where i will skip the function for index function of class

Comment: Dear thanks for prompt reply, can you give me example of route ?

Comment: Dear thanks for prompt reply, can you give me example of route ? actually i have following route but its not working $route['(:any)'] = 'welcome/$1';