# CodeIgniter: 404 Page not found on first launch

Tags: codeigniter, http-status-code-404

Good Day, I have used codeIgniter a little but whenever we download codeIgniter framework from their website and after extraction to the server root folder. If we access the framework we usually se a **Welcome** page. But here is a different situation that I'm seeing a **404** page not found error page. I have tried a lot but unable to identify what the hack is behind showing a **404** Page instead of the beautiful **Welcome** Page.

Comment: WAMP server seems a bit tricky too. I cant access ``httpd.conf`` files  from the tray menu!

Comment: Just changed the ``$config['uri_protocol']`` from ``AUTO`` to ``PATH_INFO`` and it worked. But why?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps, but check the .htaccess and routes. I just answered a similar question here [passing variable to default controller in codeigniter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15718850/passing-variable-to-default-controller-in-codeigniter)